# USPS Rate API Working for Domestic Zip Codes Only

Tags: xml, asp-classic

My shipping quote api for USPS is working for USA zip codes only.  Canada, United Kingdom and other international zip codes result in this error:  Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8' Object required:  xmlRate.selectSingleNode(...)' /folder/subfolder/usps_plugin.asp, line 32.

Here is the code for that file:

```
<%

function GetUSPSRate(SourceZip, DestZip, Weight, Method)
    dim xml
    dim post

    post = "<RateV4Request USERID='MYUSPSUSERNAME'>" & _
        "<Revision/>" & _
        "<Package ID='1ST'>" & _
        "<Service>" & Method & "</Service>" & _
        "<ZipOrigination>" & SourceZip & "</ZipOrigination>" & _
        "<ZipDestination>" & DestZip & "</ZipDestination>" & _
        "<Pounds>" & Weight & "</Pounds>" & _
        "<Ounces>0</Ounces>" & _
        "<Container>RECTANGULAR</Container>" & _
        "<Size>LARGE</Size>" & _
        "<Width>12</Width>" & _
        "<Length>12</Length>" & _
        "<Height>12</Height>" & _
        "<Girth>12</Girth>" & _
        "</Package>" & _
        "</RateV4Request>"

    set xml = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    xml.open "GET", "http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=RateV4&XML=" & post
    xml.send("")

    dim xmlRate
    set xmlRate = xml.responseXML


    GetUSPSRate = xmlRate.selectSingleNode("//Rate").text
end function

function GetUSPSRates(SourceZip, DestZip, Weight)
    dim rates
    set rates = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    rates.add "USPS Express", GetUSPSRate(SourceZip, DestZip, Weight, "EXPRESS")
    rates.add "USPS Priority", GetUSPSRate(SourceZip, DestZip, Weight, "PRIORITY")
'   rates.add "USPS First Class", GetUSPSRate(SourceZip, DestZip, Weight, "FIRST CLASS")

    set GetUSPSRates = rates
end function
%>
```

Also, here is the code that calls for that request:

```
dim uspsRates
dim uspsKey
set uspsRates = GetUSPSRates("02196", receiverpostalcode, shipmentweight)

for each uspsKey in uspsRates
    dim uspsValue
    uspsValue = uspsRates.item(uspsKey)
    %>
    <input name="shipinfo" type="radio" value="<%= uspsValue %>|<%= uspsKey %>">$<%= uspsValue + stone_handlingfee %>&nbsp;<%= uspsKey %>
    <br>
<% next
%>
```

It works perfectly and flawlessly for domestic zip codes, however, international is when the issues occur.  Constructive input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: errr... they have a separate api for international...

Comment: I don't think there is a different api for international, I think that you're missing some inputs.  Country is a required field and you have to make sure your input matches the values in the documentation (example: Canada is CA, not CAN).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all the variables were accounted for to generate international quotes.  Country, City and Zip are the most important. Without these, the api could not return results.